# Css3 animation infinite running zoom Effect

Tags: html, css, animation

I need a help.
I want to animate the background image with the css3 below is what I am trying to do.

Its not working. Can anyone please guide me where I am lacking.

```css
div.top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:500px
}

div.top:before {
    background: url(https://custom.cvent.com/90FF1E87110A48338D439371A3FD8256/pix/d9a87cea711e4f77bab87dc9242005b3.jpg) no-repeat center 70px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.49;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /*z-index: -1;*/
    animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
    -webkit-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
    -o-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
    -moz--o-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
    transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0px, 0px);
 -o-transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Animate background image here</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is the `zoomEffect` is defined?

Comment: If you use `animation` means that you have an animation defined in your code, but you are not sharing it. Share your animation code to help you, if not this will be closed as offtopic.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not exactly an animation, it is an image scaling and zooming using css3. Thanks

Comment: in your code that you have posted. there is an `animation` named `zoomEffect` . we are asking you to share the css code for that specific animation ( code from `@keyframes zoomEffect` ) . do that, or we can't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the animation `zoomEffect`

```
@keyframes zoomEffect {
    from {transform: scale(1, 1)}
    to {transform: scale(2, 2)}
}
```

You can read more about it here: [CSS3 Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
div.top {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px
}
div.top:before {
  background: url(https://custom.cvent.com/90FF1E87110A48338D439371A3FD8256/pix/d9a87cea711e4f77bab87dc9242005b3.jpg) no-repeat center 70px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.49;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
  animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
  -webkit-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
  -o-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
  -moz--o-animation: 50s ease 0s normal none infinite running zoomEffect;
}

@keyframes zoomEffect {
    from {transform: scale(1, 1)}
    to {transform: scale(2, 2)}
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Animate background image here</div>
```